# how do I find a value within a string in php

Tags: php, string

My value is stored within a string inside (). I need to return this value to check if it's empty.

```
$variable = "<a href=\"http://www.link-url.ext\">My Link</a> (55)";
$value = "55"; // how do I get the value?

if($value < 1) { 
    // no link
} else {
    // show link
}
```

This code would be used to show links with no posts in them in Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$variable = "My Link (55) plus more text";
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/',$variable,$matches);

$value = $matches[1];
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't quite make sense - although you should look at using instr

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the value from your string. But if you just need to know whether the value is empty, checking whether your string contains `()` should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a string's value, or just check to see if it is empty?

If your checking if the string is empty try

```
return empty($mystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(strpos($string,')')-strpos($string,'(')==1)){
  #empty
}
```

to return the string

```
$newstring = substr($string,strpos($string,'('),strpos($string,')')-strpos($string,'('));
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php
$str = "blah blah blah blah blah blah blah (testing)blah blah blah blah blah ";

echo preg_filter("/.*(\(.*?\)).*/","\\1",$str);
?>
```

Would output (testing). Hopefully that is what you were looking for :o)

Answer (score 0):

Putting all of this together, it is clear from the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071245/how-do-i-find-a-value-within-a-string-in-php/#question) that [InnateDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291806/innatedev) intends to test against **positive** *numeric values* inside the parentheses. In my opinion, the safest way to do this would be:

```
$testString = "<a href=\"http://www.link-url.ext\">My Link</a> (55)";
$matches = array();

/* Assuming here that they never contain negative values e.g. (-55) */
preg_match('/\((\d*?)\)/s', $testString, $matches);

$hasComments = false;

if (count($matches) >= 1) // * Note A
{
    $hasComments = $matches[1] > 0;
}

if ($hasComments)
{
    // link
}
else
{
    // no link
}
```

*Note A:* Maybe this is redundant, in which case you're free to ignore it - this can also go as a comment to [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071245/how-do-i-find-a-value-within-a-string-in-php/3071353#3071353) (sorry, don't have those 50 rep yet :( ) - if you're working in an environment where **error_reporting** includes **E_NOTICE** and if the tested string comes from an untrusted source then `$matches[1]` will raise a notice when no parantheses are present. Just wanted to point this one out.